# [None]*n vs [None for _ in range(n)]

Tags: python-3.x, list, initialization

I am trying to create lists of size `n` and initialize with `None`.

Which is better, `[None]*n` or `[None for _ in range(n)]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure, but `[None]*n` should be faster because it's only multiplication, while `[None for _ in range(n)]` is a loop.

Answer (score 1):

[You can time it yourself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). You don't need to initialize empty lists in python though. Why are you doing this?